# Where can I find names for cryptographic notation I don't recognize?

Tags: reference-request, notation

I'm new to this space and find myself stumbling over come cryptographic/mathematical notation. Search engines are not very helpful when copying and pasting Greek letters. Is there any reference that can at least give me names of what I am looking for?

Comment: Is this of any use? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols

Comment: Not really. There are quite a lot of ways of writing down things mathematically and particular persons will have their own preferred ways of writing things down. A good paper will however clearly define the possibly unknown constructs. Otherwise this is probably more a math question. There are some common usages such as $H$ or $h$ for hash, $E$ for encryption, $D$ for decryption...

Comment: Furthermore, if the greek letter has not been defined in the surrounding context then it's likely it's not cryptographic notation at all but some quasi-universal notation that the reader is expected to be familiar with (e.g. $\sum$ for sums, $\prod$ indicating a product). You learn these by doing math, and @djsutho's table can help in that case too (also, if you know it's greek, you can https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_alphabet to find the letter's name and google it)

Comment: I can't think of a lot of greek letters used by default specifically in crypto, with the maybe confusing $\eta$ (eta) and $\mu$ (mu). The first one represents the *security parameter* and the second one is used to describe a *negligible function*. Other than that, it can be a general convention (not crypto-specific) or a choice of the author (which should be specified before usage. If it does not fill any of the categories, feel free to post it and we might try to interpret it.

Comment: @SergioAndrésFigueroaSantos I think it's the other way around ($\mu$ the security parameter, $\eta$ negligible).

Comment: ...and that's why I don't like that ambiguous choice of notation! According to my reference, however, my version was correct. I hope it's not a typo, because then it would be even more confusing, but here it is (pages 8 and 9) https://courses.cs.ut.ee/all/MTAT.07.002/2015_spring/uploads/notes.pdf

Comment: @djsutho that's a great start. I guess beyond that I can rely on context and ask specific questions when something is unclear.

Comment: hmm, I'll go with "ask a question on this site" :)